# Regarding logic of intercept points

Tags: amplifier

In the picture bellow we have the fundamental plot and the third order intercept plot.
I have few questions regarding this plot.

1. The fundamental starts from positive P<sub>out</sub>. Why is that?
2. Why does the P<sub>out</sub> point at P<sub>in</sub> = 0 of the funcdamental called gain?
3. Why does thethird order intermodulation at P<sub>in</sub> = 0 cut the P<sub>out</sub> at negative point?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The fundamental starts from positive Pout. Why is that?

Because the amplifier has gain. If it produced a loss (Pout < 0 dBm for Pin of 0 dBm), it wouldn't be a very good amplifier.

> 2.why does the pout point at pin=0 of the funcdamental called gain?

You could use any input power level you want to calculate the gain according to

$$ G = P_{\rm out} - P_{\rm in}$$
(with power expressed in dBm and gain in dB). It's convenient to use 0 dBm since subtracting 0 from something is easy to do in your head.

> Why does the third order intermodulation at Pin = 0 cut the Pout at negative point?

Because the amplifier is designed for use at above 0 dBm input, so it was designed to have 3rd order intermodulation well below 0 dBm at that input level.

For an amplifier designed to be used with tiny inputs (-30 dBm, say), it might be different.

Comment: Hello, I have a problem understanding the OIP3 formula logic shown in the slide of the link.
i know that delta is the power difference between the IM3 and the fundamental.
(output)delta decreases by -2dB as input increases by 1dB.
i cant see from this grapg why OIP3=P_fundamental+0.5*P_delta  ?
Thanks.
https://ibb.co/QbMHdhk

Comment: @lub2354, P1 in the slide isn't "fundamental" as far as I can see. It's just some arbitrary point where gain and IM3 have been measured. Then if IM3 increases 30 dB and Pout increases 10 dB  for every 10 dB increase in Pin, then delta decreases by 20 dB for every 10 dB increase in Pin, and you will have to increase Pin  by 0.5*delta before you get to the intercept point.

Answer (score 1):

**For items 1 and 3**: The graph is scaled in decibels; it's not a linear graph where all responses are shown passing through 0, 0. In "decibel graphs" the axes represent real positive numbers (even though the decibel representation of a real positive number may be negative in magnitude).

**For item 2**: It's likely that the y axis crosses the x axis at the reference input power for the input hence, the power out response will indicate the gain on the y axis.